# JetBrains PhpStorm 2018.2: Error while fetching external resource (xmlns, schemaLocation, xsd)

Tags: xsd, typo3, phpstorm, fluid, jetbrains-ide

I want to use autocompletion at my typo3 fluid templates for some viewhelpers i.e. vhs, but PhpStorm could not fetch the external resource. It only works, if I download the xsd schema file and "manually setup external resource". It would be very nice, If the program could do this.

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
 xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
 v:schemaLocation="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/vhs-master.xsd">
<!-- my code -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your schemaLocation doesn't work, but try replacing the XSD URL with one you get from https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/ and re-download the schema from there. You'll have to pick a specific version, though.

The schemas there are generated fresh with a couple of fixes to the XML source they contain. Nothing that I expect would affect the download.

One thing though - both those URLs are served with a multi-hostname SSL certificate which means the version of openSSL you use must be at least I think it was 0.94.4 in order to be compatible. If your OS is very old it might help to update the openSSL library or do an OS update. But in all cases it should work if you use a browser to download since all current browsers understand SNI.

Comment: I got the same error "Error while fetching http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers". I'm using Win 7 Pro with the latest updates.

Comment: This points to the real error - you're trying to download the NS URL, not the XSD schema URL. The NS URL is an identifier, not a real URL that serves any content. Correct that problem and I think you've solved your issue!

Comment: I thought it automatically detects the schemalocation Url. There is no option "fetch external resource" at schemalocation Url. When I insert the xsd Url at xmlns, then it's not working anyway.